# What file encodings is the unix command "file -i" able to identify?

Tags: unix

What file encodings is the unix command "file -i" able to identify?

The man page does not exist the possible file encodings that "file -i" is able to identify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know whart your system has necessarily.   `/usr/share/misc/magic`  has the patterns that the file command uses to identify file flavors.  You can edit that file and see what is available.

The `file -i` outputs information in mime format. But file can only determine file types based on the magic file, not the output types, because the output is mime encoded.  I would take one of each flavor of file that you and see what you get for output.

You do realize that there are many platforms represented in the magic file, so enumerating everything would be both an antique-collecting activity and an incredible effort.  That may be why google does not find much.

Got an old acorn?